# Windows phone 7: How can I receive headers response from server

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm a beginner in programming.
I want to receive and display response headers, I've tried http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.headers.aspx - it works.
How can I receive and display (e.g. to textbox) headers in Windows phone 7 Silverlight? Can you help me with coding?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  First, why are you wanting to display the headers?  It seems like if you are using the headers for content, those should be in the response payload of your call

Comment: there is only one reason to display it - to watch how it works (test).

Comment: You can put a breakpoint (F9 in Visual Studio, with coursor on interesting line) and run your app. It will stop execution on that point and you can see what is stored in your vars.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/awtaffxb(v=vs.100).aspx  this is a better way to test your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can show them in this way:

```
var str = string.Empty;    
for(int i=0; i < myHttpWebResponse.Headers.Count; ++i)
{  
   str+= string.Format("\nHeader Name:{0}, Value :{1}",myHttpWebResponse.Headers.Keys[i],myHttpWebResponse.Headers[i]);    
}
MessageBox.Show(str);
```

Anyway, for testing I'd use debugger.

Some HowTo for [MessageBox](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/delivering-message-using).

Comment: No, I won't. But I can help you, if you have some specific question. Visit this page, please: www.whathaveyoutried.com :)